# SharePoint 2010 OOB Approval Workflow - Missing Status Column

Tags: workflow-activity

In a Doc library in one of our sub sites, there are multiple OOB Approval workflows that get started manually.

The Power User who creates these created an additional one this week (there are 5 other Approval workflows associated with the lib). There are 6 instances of the newly created workflow currently running, but the associated status column never appeared in the doc library.

It is not just hidden in the view, it is not one of the selectable columns, period. The workflow is working fine in all other respects. I opened the lib in SharePoint Designer and it does show the workflow as associated.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your power user hit the Resource Throttling limit of 8 on List View Lookup Threshold, which limits the number or lookup columns in a view (including workflow, user, mananged metadata)

When you start a new workflow the first time you should make sure you don't hit that limit in the current view as this will cause the corresponding column not to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I see this post is a bit old, but I just had this same issue and had been searching and experimenting to find a solution. I was near admitting defeat...

I made a list with one primary lookup column, with 8 'additional fields' selected on that lookup. There are 2 'people or group' columns in addition to the default, and 4 workflows.
Only 1 workflow was showing in the view or as an option for the view.
After deleting and re-adding the other 3 workflows, 1 more showed up in the view after being run, but any additional would not.
I heard about the non-obvious reference, or lookup, column limit that limited these workflows from showing as available columns for the view. So, I deleted some of the lookup column additional fields, but it didn't make a difference. Initially.

My workaround that, so far, worked:

I deleted most "additional field" lookup selections so that I only had a couple lookup/reference columns in the list. I deleted all workflows that were not showing after being run. I (re)added the additional workflows, ran them, and they showed. I then went back and (re)added the additional lookup column fields. The workflow statuses remained in view, new ones appeared, and the lookup columns display the expected data.

I've heard there is a limit to keep the views from "breaking," but this workaround has provided what I needed and after a few tests has continued to do so. I hope it helps others as well.